# Version mismatch global tsc 1.0.3.0 != VS Code's language service (2.2.1)

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

I have this popup presented:
[image]

I tried to install the proper tsc by following commands in cmd:

`npm install --g --save-dev typescript@2.2.1`
and
`npm install --save-dev typescript@2.2.1`

but it didn't help, the popup still shows on VS Code startup.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out the problem was that I also had `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;` 
Simply removing (delete the folder 1.0) that from my path sorted the issue.
When I run

```
tsc --version
```

it now shows me 2.6.2

Answer (score 3):

Open the command prompt and type     **where tsc**

This will give you a list of typescript versions your PATH and global settings are pointing to.

Go to the path: C:\xxxxx\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript

then delete the older version folder except latest one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the command palette and type `Open User Settings`
2. Add the following as a top level property of the JSON file

   ```
   "typescript.check.tscVersion": false
   ```

That said, VS Code is warning you about a legitimate point of error where running `tsc` will have different behavior depending on the working directory.

If after running

```
npm install -g typescript
```

the following still does not reflect the new version installed

```
> tsc --version
```

check your path environmental variable. Make sure it includes "DRIVE:\profilepath\AppData\Roaming\npm"

---

I installed nodejs, then in cmd i get:

```
C:\Users\xxx>npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\xxxr\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- typescript@2.3.1


C:\Users\xxx>tsc --version
Version 1.0.3.0
```

Comment: `tsc --version` does not reflect it is still 1.0.3. And there is no npm file here `:\profilepath\AppData\Roaming\npm` what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by no npm file? What operating system are you running? I'm assume it is Windows since you mention `cmd`

Comment: There is npm folder or file in the specified directory.

Comment: I just installed it, the node.js and I have the same version installed globaly, I updated the main post.

Comment: run `where tsc`

Comment: I had the same exact issue. I fixed it by repairing (re-installing) node.js.  See my original post where a part of the problem was this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320023/typescript-angular-cli-npm-vs-code-property-property-does-not-exist-on-typ

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions):

> This message is **benign** and is meant to alert the user to the possible differences between the compiler error output and errors detected by the active language service.

So you could just ignore the warning by clicking `Don't Check Again` or by setting `"typescript.check.tscVersion": false` in File > Preferences > Settings

Or

You could **use a different TypeScript version** by default:

Open the command prompt and type `where tsc`:

[image: where tsc result]

This will give you a list of typescript versions your PATH and global settings are pointing to.

The `..\Roaming\npm\` folder is the location where npm installed typescript globally, so if you want to point to that location by default open `File > Preferences > Settings`, find the `"typescript.tsdk"` and set the value to the path of the `tsserver.js` file which is in the `typescript\lib` folder

So your setting should look something like this:

[image]