# VS code not using latest version of tsc

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

When I run `tsc -v` from VS code or from a normal command prompt, it reports version 1.0.3.0, yet when I run the command from the node.js command prompt it reports version 2.6.1. I'm using windows 10.

I have tried running `npm install -g typescript` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677633/4051181) (although I'll freely admit I don't know if their issue is the same as mine or not). I did this in the integration console within VS code. This gave the following output:

```
C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
+ typescript@2.6.1
updated 1 package in 3.716s
```

To my mind, this would suggest that the update was successful, but running `tsc -v` from the terminal in VS Code still gives 1.0.3.0.

I have also tried adding `"typescript.tsdk": "C:/Users/Tim/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib"` to my user settings, but this has also made no difference.

How can I make VS code use the later version of tsc?

Comment: What is the node.js command prompt?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know. I'm quite new to node, and all that goes along with it. I've installed node from the website, and in the list of programs on my start menu I now have `node.js` and `node.js command prompt`. Visually it's the standard windows command prompt, but there seems to be some difference behind the scenes.

Comment: This seems like a PATH issue.  My guess is that you have some old program installed which is placing `tsc` on the PATH ahead of your NPM installed typescript.  Can you look in the installed programs list for something like `Typescript Tools` and uninstall it?