# Very old angular project problems

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I have a problem installing node and typescript for a very old angular project that isn't mine

> it's using angular 2.4.10
>
> So I installed node 6.9.5 through the exe i found
>
> And I'm trying to install typescript 2.0.10

Results:

C:\Windows\System32>node -v

> v6.9.5

[Project folder]>npm install -g typescript@2.0.10

> C:\Users[MyName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users[MyName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
> C:\Users[MyName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users[MyName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
> C:\Users[MyName]\AppData\Roaming\npm
> `-- typescript@2.0.10

[Project folder]>tsc -v

> Version 1.0.3.0

i have no error, just never get the proper version to be there

Comment: Probably [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676984/version-mismatch-global-tsc-1-0-3-0-vs-codes-language-service-2-2-1). I would try to run `where tsc` and start digging from there. Thats described in the answers.

Comment: I managed to make it work for some reason by installing latest and then doing the same command and now it's at 2.0.10

Now what I have is > gulp build.dev --color

[15:22:18] Requiring external module ts-node/register
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

So I was in some versioning problems. What I did was
-install latest
-check that the package.json changed
-install the version I wanted

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).